# Constructing linked Java objects from constructors

Tags: java, arrays, object, inheritance, polymorphism

I've been getting frustrated trying to wrap my head around OOD. I'm trying to build a program that has three classes - one called Person which would have a constructor consisting of personal information. Another class called Doctor which inherits the Person class and simply constructs an object with an extra field (most of the fields, i.e. name, address will point to the person object) called specialty. I use another class to build the java application to create, view and modify the fields in the person and doctor objects.

I've built both the person and doctor classes, and you can find the relevant code for them at the bottom of this post. The problem occurs when I try creating doctor objects as my code seems to be creating an entirely new doctor object with no relation whatsoever to the person object. I've attempted editing the firstName string of a person object, but the doctor object isn't updated to reflect that. It seems to have created it's own permanent name as opposed to simply pointing at the name defined in the person object.

I create person objects through user input and store them using the following line.

```
        persons[amountPersons] = new Person (firstName, lastName,   homeAddress, phoneNumber);
        amountPersons++;
```

Once a person object is created, the user can input the personNumber and create a doctor object like so

```
    person = getPersonID(personID);

        int personNumber;
        String firstName = null; 
        String lastName = null;
        String homeAddress = null;
        String phoneNumber = null;


        firstName = person.firstName;
        lastName = person.lastName;
        homeAddress = person.homeAddress;
        phoneNumber = person.phoneNumber;
        personNumber = person.personNumber;

        System.out.print ("Enter speciality of the doctor: ");  
        String speciality = input.nextLine();

        doctors[amountDoctors] = new Doctor (firstName, lastName, homeAddress, phoneNumber, speciality);
        amountDoctors++;
```

What on earth am I doing wrong? Apologies for the large amount of code - I've slimmed it down as best I can, but I'm not sure where the problem is so I can only do that so much.

**Person Class**

```
public class Person {

//Instance Variables 
protected String firstName;
protected String lastName;
protected String homeAddress; 
protected String phoneNumber; 
protected int personNumber;

private static int NumberSystem = 1;



public Person()
{
firstName = " ";
lastName = " ";
homeAddress = " ";
phoneNumber = " ";
personNumber = 0;
}


public Person (String firstName, String lastName, String homeAddress, String phoneNumber)
{
// Initialize instance variables
this.firstName = firstName;
this.lastName = lastName;
this.homeAddress = homeAddress;
this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
personNumber = NumberSystem;
NumberSystem = NumberSystem + 1;
}


public String toString()
{
    String p;
    p = "=================================================" +"\n" +
        "Identification Number: " + personNumber +"\n" +
        "Name: " + firstName +"\n" +
        "Surname: " + lastName +"\n" +
        "Address: " + homeAddress +"\n" +
        "Mobile/Telephone: " + phoneNumber +"\n";
return p;

}
```

**Doctor**

```
public class Doctor extends Person{

// the aim of Doctor subclass is to simply add a speciality field
private String speciality;
int doctorID;

public Doctor() {
    doctorID = 0;
    speciality = "none";
}


public Doctor(String firstName, String lastName, String homeAddress, String phoneNumber, String speciality) {
    super(firstName, lastName, homeAddress, phoneNumber);
    this.speciality = speciality;
    }


public String toString()
{
    String d;
    d = "=================================================" +"\n" +
        "Doctor Number: " + doctorID +"\n" +
        "Person Number: " + personNumber +"\n" +
        "Name: " + firstName +"\n" +
        "Surname: " + lastName +"\n" +
        "Address: " + homeAddress +"\n" +
        "Mobile/Telephone: " + phoneNumber +"\n" +
        "Speciality: " + speciality +"\n";
return d;

}


}
```

Comment: It soudns to me like you're not looking for inheritance, but composition. Currently, when you have a `Doctor`, it is also a `Person`, which means you can use it wherever you could use a `Person`. This does not link it to any other `Person` object though. To do that, you would need to make `Doctor` have a `Person` field rather than making it a child class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two commonly used patterns that are used when designing two objects that have a relationship with one another.

- Inheritance.  Inheritance is a powerful tool, but it is not a panacea and it comes with its own problems and limitations.  You should only use inheritance if Class B has an **is a** relationship with Class A.  For example, a mountain bike IS A bike, so it would be sensible to have a `MountainBike` class `extend` `Bike'.  If you can't say that there is an "is a" relationship, then DON'T use inheritance.
- Composition.  Composition is also a powerful tool that is arguably more robust and less fragile than inheritance.  Use composition when Class B is an attribute of Class A (or when Class A **has a** Class B).  In this case, you are making Class B an instance field of Class A.

In the model you describe, a doctor **is a** person, so it seems quite sensible to use inheritance.  Since all we can see of your domain model are the two classes you show, I would also choose to have Doctor extend Person.

As a matter of style, you should get in the habit of using the `@Override` annotation any time you intend to override a method from a base class.  When you do this, the compiler will alert you to otherwise hard to spot errors.  You should annotate the `toString()` method (which is inherited from `Object`) with `@Override`.

> The problem occurs when I try creating doctor objects as my code seems
>   to be creating an entirely new doctor object with no relation
>   whatsoever to the person object.

When you create a Doctor instance with

```
Doctor doc = new Doctor(...);
```

the object that you get is both its own type as well as its parent's type, eg. a doctor **is a** doctor, and a doctor **is a** person.  The following is legal:

```
Person person = new Doctor(...);
```

You are allowed to assign an object from a subclass to a variable of its supertype (or parent).  No new Person objects have been created, just the Doctor object (which can be assigned to a Person variable because a doctor is a person).

This is not allowed:

```
Doctor doc = new Person(...);
```

All doctors are persons, but ... not all persons are doctors so this assignment would be problematic.  The compiler won't let you do it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation between the two - I must have gotten mixed-up/confused about inheritance and composition at some point. I suppose I'll have to do some reading up on the subject matters and attempt to refresh my mind on it. However, I have one last question for possible. Let's ignore my original question where I got composition design technique mixed up with inheritance. Would you say that the doctor and person classes and the way I initialize the objects of those classes are good examples of inheritance?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your object model.  You should always try to design immutable value classes.  I would make the instance fields in both classes final (unless you can't; value objects that must comply with the JavaBeans contract can't have final fields).  Lastly, the constructors have many parameters.  These classes look like good candidates for the Builder pattern if you intend to maintain them for over a long period of time.

Answer (score 0):

The person you obtain with `person = getPersonID(personID);` is a completely different object to the doctor you create with `doctors[amountDoctors] = new Doctor (firstName, lastName, homeAddress, phoneNumber, speciality)`.

Just because they have the same e.g. firstName, etc, does not mean the objects have any relationship.

You can address this in a couple of ways.  For example, you can not create a Person followed by a Doctor, but rather just create a Doctor.  However, that doesn't reflect real life, so instead you can replace the Person you store in your array with the Doctor.

```
Person[] people = // however you initialise it;
Doctor[] doctors // however you initialise it;
```

Since a Doctor is also a Person, you can simply say `people[i] = doctor`.  Based on your code above, it might be wrapped in a method call like this:

```
// I'm assuming personID is an int, but you may need to adapt this
private void replacePerson(int personID, 
                           Person person) {
    int index = // get index of personID from the array
    people[index] = person;
}
```

and call this with

```
Doctor doctor = new Doctor (firstName, lastName, homeAddress, phoneNumber, speciality);
doctors[amountDoctors] = doctor;
amountDoctors++;
replacePerson(personID, doctor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created a `Doctor` it gets his own member variables. Think like this:

You have a `Person` which has a nameplate, addressplate etc. on his awesome jacket. Now you hand over this `Person` his plates. After that you want to promote him to a `Doctor`, but since `Doctor` inherits `Person` he also has is very own nameplate, addressplate etc. 
They are not sharing it.

So what you want to do is to use `Composition`.
e.g.

```
public class Doctor(){
  private Person person;
  private String speciality;
  public Doctor(Person person, speciality){
   this.person = person;
   this.speciality = speciality;
  }
}
```

---

Now if you change the `Person`s name, it will also update the name of all `Doctors` which are pointing out to that Person.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is what should happen. A Doctor is a Person but a Person is not a Doctor.

Now when you create a Person object you create an instance of the class Person and it is placed on the heap as an object.

Then you retrieve from that object the various fields and you use them to initialize a NEW instance of Doctor this time and place this new object to the heap. This is a distinct new object of type Doctor which is also of type Person but it is **not** the old Person object you created. This is inheritance. It would be catastrophic to work the way you would expect it.

Composition is not the right solution to your problem because it makes little sense as Doctor **is a** person not **has a** person.

What you could do though is use the **Decorator** pattern and have Doctor being an attribute that a Person could or could not have. A good tutorial would be [this](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are expecting behaviour from inheritance that just does not occur. A Doctor object does not have some relationship to a separate Person object. It Doctor **is a** Person, so it contains all the fields defined in Person, plus the ones defined in Doctor.

1. Your person[] array can store both Person and Doctor classes. But if you use `new Person()` to create the members, they will never be Doctors.
2. It is unclear why you have an array of Person and and array of Doctor.
3. Inheritance is a compile-time concept. It sounds like at runtime that you expect to have both a Person record and a Doctor record for a doctor. You will only have a Doctor record, which because of inheritance will contain all the Person fields.

Possibly a little off topic, you should reconsider if inheritance is the correct way to go. @Dragondraikk's comment is accurate. In my view the "Is a" test for inheritance should be replaced by "Is a for the life of the application". Being a Doctor is a time-constrained role that a Person plays. This points towards using composition. That way a Person can become a Doctor once they qualify, and can revert to being a Person if they are struck-off. Changing the concrete type of an object during its lifetime is never a good idea.

Apologies in advance if I have mis-interpreted your question.

Answer (score 0):

When the Doctor object is stored in memory, the allocation will be done
for fields in the superclass (Person) and then fields in the Doctor class.

So when the doctor object is stored in memory, it is one whole object not
partly a person and partly a doctor.

The only way the JVM object knows that the structure connected to the Doctor object memory allocation is a Doctor object is via a
4-byte quantity labeled "native pointer to class information."

Type safe casting  and the instanceof operator among others use this information to make out what class structure this memory allocation belongs
to.

So yes indeed the relation is of Inheritance as mentioned in the previous
answers since Doctor IS A Person ( If Doctor has Patients then it is composition )

This article by Bill Venners gives more detailed explanation on the topic..
http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/initializationP.html

One more important point is that even if Person has private variables that are not directly accessible in Doctor still when memory is allocated to a
Doctor object there is memory allocated for the private variables which
clearly indicates that the entire variable set for super and sub class
are together what constitutes the sub class.